# Does IE have a max selector length?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am using the statement given below to remove the check marks from a selected list when clear is clicked. It works perfect in FF and GC(google Chrome :-)) but not in IE.

```
$("#divResults li span .ui-icon-check").each(function () {$(this).remove(); });
```

Any idea why this does not work in IE? Are there any specific limit in the number of selectors used in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no limit known to me, but that is most likely *not* your problem. I don't know exactly what the problem is, but the selector length is certainly not it.

Comment: Do you need to be that specific ? Try if you can select `$('.ui-icon-check')`

Comment: You should post a fragment of the HTML that your selector intends to target.

Comment: `$("#divResults li span .ui-icon-check").remove();` will suffice if there's nothing else in the `.each()`

Comment: @Nick: Actually I did that initially. It was working fine in other browsers except for IE. so I tried using each. Now it works if I remove li and span out of the selectors :-).

Comment: @Raja: Are you sure your HTML is valid? Browsers will tolerate different levels of invalidity when it comes to that, test and see: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Nick: Now that I have heard from more than one of you experts I would definitely look into the HTML. Thanks for all the help :-)

Comment: If you found a solution to this question yourself, you should answer it and mark it as correct :) Thank you!

Comment: I'd try firebug light on IE.  Love me some firebug.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-icon-check", "#divResults").remove();
```